# How to access parameters or settings for guest executable during SetupEntryPoint?

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to set some environment variables in a PowerShell script run from SetupEntryPoint based on values that are different per environment for use by a guest executable hosted in Service Fabric. I haven't been able to find a way to access the environment specific parameters outside of the full client API described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928204/where-do-you-set-and-access-run-time-configuration-parameters-per-environment-fo).

One workaround I'm considering trying is writing a wrapper EXE that can use the client API to pull the configuration and then call the real EXE as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488598/in-service-fabric-can-i-alter-the-arguments-in-the-servicemanifest-xml-file-usi) but that seems way complicated just to use per environment configuration for a guest executable so I'm hoping I'm just missing a simpler option.

Comment: i suppose there's no solution to this yet

Comment: Same problem here, looking for a good samaritan :-)

Comment: I did some similar experimentation in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56773087/what-environment-variables-are-available-to-the-setupentrypoint-process/56775085#56775085). You could run a similar experiment to see what kind of parameters are provided to your SetupEntryPoint.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-how-to-specify-environment-variables) for information on how the Application/Service Manifest APIs allow you to specify environment variables for each service that can be driven off of application (per instance) parameters, while also being able to specify suitable defaults.