# What environment variables are available to the SetupEntryPoint process?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm looking to write a script to execute as a SetupEntryPoint for a Service Fabric Service. I'd like to know what environment variables would be available to the process.

The environment variables available to a running service are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-environment-variables-reference). The documentation for SetupEntryPoint may be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-run-script-at-service-startup) but does not elude to what environment variables are available to the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the following simple batch file to run as the SetupEntryPoint of my service, which dumps all environment variables available to the process to temporary file:

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -Command "& { Get-ChildItem 'env:*' | Sort-Object name | Format-Table -Wrap | Out-File 'C:/Windows/Temp/EnvVariables.txt' }"
```

After I re-deployed my test Service Fabric application, the following variables related to Service Fabric were identified (I've omitted the values for security purposes):

```
Fabric_ApplicationHostId  
Fabric_ApplicationHostType
Fabric_ApplicationId 
Fabric_ApplicationName 
Fabric_CodePackageInstanceSeqNum
Fabric_CodePackageName
Fabric_Endpoint_IPOrFQDN_RemotingEndpoint
Fabric_Endpoint_RemotingEndpoint
Fabric_Folder_App_Log          
Fabric_Folder_App_Temp         
Fabric_Folder_App_Work         
Fabric_Folder_Application      
Fabric_Folder_Application_OnHost                             
Fabric_IsCodePackageActivatorHost
Fabric_IsContainerHost         
Fabric_NodeId                  
Fabric_NodeIPOrFQDN            
Fabric_NodeName                
Fabric_PartitionId             
Fabric_RuntimeConnectionAddress
Fabric_RuntimeSslConnectionAddress
Fabric_RuntimeSslConnectionCertEncodedBytes
Fabric_RuntimeSslConnectionCertKey
Fabric_RuntimeSslConnectionCertThumbprint
Fabric_ServiceName
Fabric_ServicePackageActivationGuid
Fabric_ServicePackageActivationId
Fabric_ServicePackageInstanceSeqNum
Fabric_ServicePackageName
Fabric_ServicePackageVersionInstance
FabricActivatorAddress
FabricPackageFileName
HostedServiceName
```

Many of these can be cross-referenced with the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-environment-variables-reference). It would still be nice if these were officially documented somewhere specifically related to the SetupEntryPoint.