# Pass Environment Variable as commnadline arguments to Service Fabric main entry point

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a guest exe (third party exe)  which is being called in Service Fabric App main entry point. This needs few command line parameter which I can get only at runtime. I am thinking to set environment variable on Set up Entry point and pass it as a command line arguments to main entry point.

My question is it possible to pass Environment variable  as command line parameter.

Comment: Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488598/in-service-fabric-can-i-alter-the-arguments-in-the-servicemanifest-xml-file-usi) (which basically says "No, you can't do that", but it does offer an alternative.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass command line arguments to docker Grafana container in Service Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57516530/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-docker-grafana-container-in-service-fabric)

Answer (score 1):

Take a  look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-how-to-specify-environment-variables. It shows how to pass variables to your Service Fabric services.

Comment: The article only specify how to declare environment variables and not actually how to pass as command line argument